# play framework evolution recreate db every server restart

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

Every time I restart my play framework app server, the app evolution want me to recreate all the tables I created (The tables I created does not exist anymore).

I'm working with Intellij IDEA with play 2.4.2
The database is SQLite.
The evolutions were created using Ebean.

If I disable the Ebean auto-evolution I get error(sqlexcpetion) that the framework cant find the tables I have.

How can I fix it?

Comment: in my app evoulution are executed only when I made some changes in 1.sql script. Play detect if there are some changes in script. If yes executes evolution sctipts.

Comment: I have to ask, as AFAIK SQLite supports in-memory database style: are you using it? Because if yes this might very well be the cause of your problem...